# Implementing BFS using recursion

Tags: breadth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

How do I implement `BFS` using recursion, given the linked list representation?

I know `DFS` can be implemented using recursion, but not with `BFS`. Please suggest a possible method?

Comment: Loop over the current level twice. The first loop processes all the nodes, the second loop recurses into all the non-leaf nodes.

Comment: i have to implement in c. can u suggest a pseudo code?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `[]` represents a list.

```
f(graph, past_nodes, current_nodes, mark):
    new_nodes = all neighbors of current_nodes which are not in past_nodes
    if new_nodes == []:
        return
    else
        for each n in new_nodes:
            mark(n)
        f(graph, past_nodes union current_nodes, new_nodes, mark)
```

Begin by calling `f(graph, [], [start_node], m)` where `m` is the function you want to run for each node in BFS order.

Comment: can u explain a little?

Answer (score 0):

```
void bfs(int vertex)
{
int p;
void mark(int);
 m=g[vertex];
 if(m->v==1)
 return;
 m->v=1;
 printf("%c ",m->a);
 while(m->link!=NULL)
         {
         m=m->link;
         if(m->v==0)
            {
             m->v=1;
             p=int(m->a)-65;
             mark(p);
            }
         }

 m=g[vertex];
 while(m->link!=NULL)
         {
         m=m->link;
         bfs(p);
          }
}
```

i get stuck here.